# Dummy output, no soundcard detected

Tags: drivers, 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

To begin with I installed 'alsa', then I had to remove it using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
```

,because I get 'dummy output' as audio output.
Using `aplay -l` I get:

```
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

and with `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [1002:9840]
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [1179:fa30]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0 [1022:1538]
00:02.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1 [1022:1439]
--
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation FCH Azalia Controller [1179:fa3c]
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:780e] (rev 11)
```

---

I read a lot of post about this topic but none of them help me to solve the problem.
That's a summary of differents 'options' that I tried:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libasound2 libasound2-data libasound2-plugins alsa-base alsa-ucm-conf alsa-topology-conf alsa-utils

sudo apt-get install unity-control-center

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I had a similar issue in Lubuntu.  The solutions [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) may help.  The very first one helped for me.

Comment: @ModalNest Thank you so much